# Why doesn't the hot water work but the central heating does?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

We have a gas fired boiler (which works).  There's no problem with the central heating.  Both the hot water and central heating valves actuate automatically when they're selected on the heating control box.

The problem is that the water coming out of the hot taps is lukewarm at best, it seems to be cold and occasionally has some residual heat radiated from other pipes.  The bathroom radiator looks like it's connected to the hot water loop and gets too hot to touch when the hot water is turned on.  So I assume that the hot water exists in the system, but isn't reaching the circuit with the taps on it for some reason, only the bathroom radiator.

There seems to be quite a lot of air in this radiator, almost every day the bottom is hot and the top cold, so I've been bleeding it whenever I go in the bathroom and there's always a little air trapped in it.

Is this likely to be an air lock somewhere that's preventing the hot water from getting to the taps?  If so, is there a simple way to fix it?

Comment: open just the hot side and touch the feeder pipes on the faucet.

Comment: In most cases the water heater for domestic hot water is separate from central heating.  Your water heater can die without affecting your furnace.  The anti-scald valve could be broken or damaged in some manner.